# Losing html input values while replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace some elements within HTML code.

I clone the HTML fragment, replace some things and replace the whole html container.

The problem is, that all input fields are empty after appending. Is there a possibility to store the input values and append it?

```
var wrapper = $("<div>");
wrapper.append($(this).clone());

var newInput = wrapper.html().replace(/xy/g,"yz");
$(this).empty();
$(this).append(newInput);
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Provide your html code first.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create and tidy a [mcve]